# Modify string values of a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': ['c10:b', 'c11', 'c12:k'], 'c2': ['c20', 'c21', 'c22']})

     c1    c2
0   c10:b  c20
1   c11    c21
2   c12:k  c22
```

I'd like to modify the string values of column c1 so that everything after (and including) the colon removes, so it ends up like this:

```
     c1    c2
0   c10    c20
1   c11    c21
2   c12    c22
```

I've tried slicing

```
df[’c1’].str[:df[’c1’].str.find(’:’)]
```

but it doesn't work. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `replace` with `regex=True`:

```
df.replace(r'\:.*', '', regex=True)
```

```
    c1   c2
0  c10  c20
1  c11  c21
2  c12  c22
```

To only replace this pattern in a single column, use the `str` accessor:

```
df.c1.str.replace(r'\:.*', '')
```

If performance is a concern, use a list comprehension and `partition` instead of `pandas` string methods:

```
[i.partition(':')[0] for i in df.c1]
# ['c10', 'c11', 'c12']
```

***Timings***

```
df = pd.concat([df]*10000)

%timeit df.replace(r'\:.*', '', regex=True)
30.8 ms ± 340 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit df.c1.str.replace(r'\:.*', '')
31.2 ms ± 449 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit df['c1'].str.partition(':')[0]
56.7 ms ± 269 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit [i.partition(':')[0] for i in df.c1]
4.2 ms ± 22.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```